# Event Receiver for Document Library

Tags: sharepoint, events, list

I'm trying to update one of the properties of a word document from an event receiver.

I'm handling it with the ***ItemAdded*** event and updating the property as is:

```
// Modify property
DisableEventFiring();
properties.ListItem.File.CheckOut();
properties.AfterProperties[HelloWorldInternalFieldName] = "Hello World!";
properties.ListItem.UpdateOverwriteVersion();
properties.ListItem.File.CheckIn("Updating Property!");
properties.ListItem.SystemUpdate();
EnableEventFiring();
```

I'm getting an exception when I'm trying to modify it and it is saying:

> The event does not support change of
>   properties.

Does anyone have an idea why and why I cannot update the property after I save the document to the document library in Word?

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I know what the problem is:

AfterProperties is read-only in -"ed" events.
You can just modify the list item:

```
properties.ListItem["HelloWorldInternalFieldName"] = "Hello World!";
```